# Read HDF - Dealing with Hierarchy via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

I would like to read an hdf5 file `2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5`. The file has parent groups: `0000` `0001` `0002` etc. Each parent group has child groups `data` and `grid`.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd

data = h5py.File('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', 'r')
print(list(data.keys()))
```

```
['0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', '0010', ...
```

```
print(list(data['0000'].keys()))
```

```
['data', 'grid']
```

```
data['0000']['data']
```

```
<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (101, 128, 128, 1), type "<f4">
```

```
df = pd.read_hdf('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', key='0000')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_hdf('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', '0000')

File ~/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py:442, in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, errors, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, **kwargs)
    437                 raise ValueError(
    438                     "key must be provided when HDF5 "
    439                     "file contains multiple datasets."
    440                 )
    441         key = candidate_only_group._v_pathname
--> 442     return store.select(
    443         key,
    444         where=where,
    445         start=start,
    446         stop=stop,
    447         columns=columns,
    448         iterator=iterator,
    449         chunksize=chunksize,
    450         auto_close=auto_close,
    451     )
    452 except (ValueError, TypeError, KeyError):
    453     if not isinstance(path_or_buf, HDFStore):
    454         # if there is an error, close the store if we opened it.
...
   1679         )
   1680 else:
   1681     if isinstance(value, Series):

TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

`df = pd.read_hdf('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', key='0000/data')` returns the same error. If it is not possible to use Pandas for this, a h5py solution will have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your HDF5 file was not created with Pandas (and Pandas expects a certain format/schema to read h5 files). I created 2 test files to demonstrate the difference based on the package used to create the file. Code to create the 2 files is at the end.

Start by interrogating the HDF5 file with the `.info()` method from the `pandas.HDFStore` API. See below:

```
with pd.HDFStore('SO_76007953_pd.h5') as h5_store:
    print(h5_store.info())
```

This will create A LOT of output if the file was created with Pandas. Output for the file I created with Pandas:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: SO_76007953_pd.h5
/0000/data            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
/0000/grid            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
/0001/data            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
/0001/grid            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
/0002/data            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
/0002/grid            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->1,indexers->[index],dc->[])
```

However, if it was NOT created with Pandas, you will get very little output. Output for a file created with h5py:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: SO_76007953.h5
Empty
```

If your file was created with Pandas, you should be able to read the datasets with the following:

```
df_d = pd.read_hdf('SO_76007953_pd.h5', key='/0000/data')
df_g = pd.read_hdf('SO_76007953_pd.h5', key='/0000/grid')
```

However, based on your comments, I expect you will get "Empty" when you check your h5 file. That's why `pd.read_hdf()` doesn't work. If so, you need to use another package (`h5py` or PyTables aka `tables`).

Here is a short code segment shows how to open your file with h5py, loop over the groups, and read the `data` and `grid` datasets into either an h5py dataset object or a numpy array.

```
with h5py.File('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5') as h5f:
    for g_name, g_obj in h5f.items():
        print(g_name) 
        data_ds = g_obj['data']  # this returns a h5py dataset object
        data_arr = g_obj['data'][()]  # this returns a numpy object
        grid_ds = g_obj['grid']
        grid_arr = g_obj['grid'][()]
```

Here is code to create 2 HDF5 files, 1 with Pandas and the other with h5py. Run them both, then inspect with HDFView. When you do, you will see several differences.

1. The `grid` and `data` keys in the Pandas file will be groups (not datasets) and the data will be in groups and datasets below each key/group.
2. The Pandas file will also have a lot of attributes: 4 at the root level and 15 for each grid`and`data` key/group.

Code to create with Pandas:

```
for i in range(3):
    df_g = pd.DataFrame( [(v+10*i) for v in range(10)] )  
    df_d = pd.DataFrame( [(v/10.+10*i) for v in range(10) ] )
    grp = f'{i:04d}'
    df_g.to_hdf('SO_76007953_pd.h5', key=grp+'/grid', mode='a', format='table')  
    df_d.to_hdf('SO_76007953_pd.h5', key=grp+'/data', mode='a', format='table')
```

Code to create with h5py:

```
with h5py.File('SO_76007953.h5','w') as h5f:
    for i in range(3):
        grp = h5f.create_group(f'{i:04d}')
        grp.create_dataset('grid', data=[ (v+10*i) for v in range(10)] )        
        grp.create_dataset('data', data=[ (v/10.+10*i) for v in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small error in the key definition. PyTables (the package Pandas uses to read HDF5 data), needs the path defined starting with '/'. Try this:

```
df_d = pd.read_hdf('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', key='/0000/data') # include the leading /    
df_g = pd.read_hdf('2D_rdb_NA_NA.h5', key='/0000/grid') # same
```

Comment: I get the same error: `TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed`

Comment: I also made a small edit to my question: `data['0000']['data']` returns `<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (101, 128, 128, 1), type "<f4">`. Maybe that gives more information.

Comment: Yeah, I created some test files to compare files from pandas vs h5py. Then I made a mistake when testing `pd.read_hdf()` with each file, and came to the wrong conclusion above. See new answer below.